# Installing mobilefirst server in distant server

Tags: server, device, mobilefirst-server

Good days 
we are working in project which consiste to read an xml file by http adapter,
we want to run aplication in many physic device,so we have configured the wlclient-properties file in ourApp->android->native->assets, which the ip of our machine.
the problem is when our machine is off the app doest run well,so we deside to instal our mobilefirst server in distant server. if it is the correct solution please help us.if it is not the correct way please explin how to fixe this problem.
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I recall from a previous question by you that you're using MobileFirst Studio in your developer workstation. MobileFirst Studio is the "developer edition" of the product you're using.

If you want to install it in a "remote server", i.e. not an instance of MobileFirst Studio, you need to actually **purchase a product license** from IBM.

If you are a company, I suggest that your business department to contact IBM. See here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/help/

Only by being a customer, you can download the required files to install a server on a remote machine.

Otherwise, you could upgrade from MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 to MobileFirst Foundation 8.0. In v8.0 you can now easily create a server instance on IBM's Bluemix - on the cloud.

If you are ready to upgrade, read here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/bluemix/using-mobile-foundation/

Comment: i get MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 and create my bluemix account !
how to create an instance of server on IBM's Bluemix ?
Thank you

Comment: Did you actually follow the tutorial? By following the tutorial you will have a server running... Follow The Tutorial:  https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/bluemix/using-mobile-foundation/

Comment: Now My Index.html file don't change 
i change i save configue and build my projet !!
When i run , the the web page stay to "welcome to mobilefirst" 
Where is the probleme please